# What is the fastest way of loading huge data(100 gb) in vertica database?

Tags: database, etl, data-warehouse, vertica, dataloader

"What is the fastest way of loading data in vertica database ? If i have 100 GB of data which i need to laod in vertica table in a fast and efficient way."

Answer (score 2):

I would say the fastest of all is the standard COPY command:
`COPY myschema.mytable FROM '/data/common/mytable.csv' ON ANY NODE`
Plus any other necessary parameters for column delimiter, string encloser, error handling, etc.

And, `/data/common` , here, would be a file location that is NFS-mounted to the same directory on all nodes of Vertica.

If `/data/common/mytable.csv` is not gzipped, you also allow for *apportioned load*: If you have, for example, 8 parse streams, each will grab 1/8th of the complete file volume (navigating to the nearest newline or other record delimiter) and just parse that part, all in parallel.

I can't imagine a faster way - hope this helps.